# Ajax Response Doesn't work from server side (iis)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to save a file (image) on C# MVC and JS with the following function js

```
      function Add() {
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#txtUploadFile").get(0).files;
            var cod = document.getElementById('cod').value;
            var mat = document.getElementById('mat').value;
            var status = document.getElementById('status').value;
            var plant = document.getElementById('plant').value;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                        data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                        data.append("mat", mat);
                        data.append("status", status);
                        data.append("plant", plant);
                        data.append("code", cod);
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Pred/Admin/AddPred',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (response) {
                                if(response.msg == 1)
                                {
                                    refreshTable(response.data);
                                }
                                alert('Predio agregado.');

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

and on the codebehind I used it

```
public ActionResult AddPred()
        {
            int isInsert=0;
            string route = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAPS_ROUTE"];
            string[] status, plants, mats, codes;
            int stat;
            try
            {
                var requeststatus = Request.Params;
                status = requeststatus.GetValues("status");
                plants = requeststatus.GetValues("plant");
                codes = requeststatus.GetValues("cod");
                mats = requeststatus.GetValues("mat");
                if (status[0] == "On")
                    stat= 1;
                else
                    stat= 0;
                string plant = plants[0];
                string mat = mats[0];
                string code = codes[0];
                foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                {
                    var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
                    if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = fileContent.FileName;
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(route), fileName);
                        path = Server.MapPath(route) + fileName;
                        var sqlpath = "." + route + "/" + fileName;
                        fileContent.SaveAs(path);
                        isInsert = ma.InsertPred(code, mat, stat, plant, sqlpath);                        
                    }
                }
                merge.preds = ma.GetPreds();
                return Json(new { success = true, data = merge.preds, msg = isInsert }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json("add failed");
            }

        }
```

But the server response ever is

> POST myserver/Preds/Admin/AddPred 500 (Internal Server Error)

and I used console.log but I can't to get the error information, When used this code on local side, it's runs Okey, save the image and return model for refresh the front, but when put the aplication on the server, only return error, others funtions works (modal show, return model with json) but doesn't work save a image, I set permissions (write, load, modify) on the server folder,

someone give a idea for solves this problem, I don't know whats wrong

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what the issue is. What is `merge`? Is `id` being filled? Why are you returning a `View` when your jQuery is expecting JSON? Without context the code itself seems ok.

Comment: you have to return json data not view ...view means html

Comment: yes the ID its filled, merge is where save the data, and I tryed with both returns but I don't know how set the new data into the Model on the front

Comment: @PranayRana when I used a return json, how set this data and the view show it

Comment: if you retrun json data then you need to crete json object via javascript and if you are using jquery than assing value to your control one by one

Comment: Thx, I'm trying it and I can to set new data into model, only I need to write conditions, thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
 function getCities(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Default")",
        data: '{id: id }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        //alert(response.responseData);
         window.location = '/Default/YourView';//

    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error!");  //
    }
    });
}


 //In your controller  
public JsonResult Index(string id)
{
    merge.country= mp.Country();
    merge.city= mp.City(id);

    return Json("you can return an object or a string, what you want");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't change the data in the database ? If you put a breakpoint, what is happenning in Index ? Can you get the id parameter ? If yes, you should change inside of index method because it will throw an exception. mp and merge objects are null.

Comment: the ID its filled and in the code behind the merge class get the new values, but on the front the new data doesn't shows, I have only one front and when press any button I want to change the data on the front, dynamic

Comment: You should return your new data and refresh your data on the front. return Json() takes an object. For exemple, if you return an object obj with the parameter ID, in your html, on the success methode of your ajax methode you can acces the parameter ID like response.ID; (response is the value that your controller methode returns.

Comment: Thx for all, I did it, with the refresh like you said